# JFileChooser, save multiple file types

Tags: java, file, types, filepath, jfilechooser

I have no problem opening multiple file types, however I want the option to be able to save multiple file types. I can't figure out how to get the option the user selected to save their file types as.

Here is my code:

```
    //.txt and .encm files are allowed
    final JFileChooser txtOrEncmChooser = new JFileChooser(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));


    //only allow user to use .txt and .encm files
    txtOrEncmChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Encrypted Data File (*.encm)", "encm"));
    txtOrEncmChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text File (*.txt)", "txt"));
    txtOrEncmChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        //displays save file dialog
        int returnVal = txtOrEncmChooser.showSaveDialog(FileEncryptionFilter.this);

        //use chose to save file
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
                //selects file
                File fileName = txtOrEncmChooser.getSelectedFile();

        /****The problem is here, how do I figure out what file type the user selected?****/

                    if .txt is selected{
                    String filePath = fileName.getPath() + ".txt"; //file path
                    }
                    else if .encm is selected
                    {
                    String filePath = fileName.getPath() + ".encm"; //file path
                    }
        }
```

I have searched the forums for solutions, but I only found the solution for opening multiple file types, not saving multiple file types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getFileFilter()

```
FileNameExtensionFilter f = (FileNameExtensionFilter) txtOrEncmChooser.getFileFilter();
```

Since `getExtensions()` returns an array, you'll have to iterate through all the extensions. If you are sure that it only contains one element, of course, you won't need to do this. Just check `f.getExtensions()[0].equals("txt")`, for example. You could also create your file filters as local variables and then compare them with the selected one.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Now my other question is why does getExtensions return an array? I don't understand how I would end up having more than one element in my case.

Comment: @TommySaechao In your case there's only one, but sometimes you might wanna add multiple extensions. `jpg` and `jpeg` are a typical example. That's why the method was written this way. Also, it'd be nice if you could accept my answer. :)